# Routing Error, receive [Get] instead of [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm trying to make a link to destroy an row in a table but the problem is that I receive [GET] instead of [DELETE].

Here the error:
No route matches [GET] "/clubs/1/club_accounting/2"

My route is :
club_club_accounting_delete_path
DELETE
/clubs/:club_id/club_accounting/:id(.:format)
club_accounting#delete

My link :

```
<%= link_to 'Supprimer', club_club_accounting_delete_path(:id => activity.id), method: :delete %>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `method: :delete` option in the `link_to` helper adds the attribute `data-method="delete"` to the resultant `<a>` tag. This is then handled by the `jquery_ujs` javascript file. Make sure it's included correctly and that it shows up in your page source. If it's there, open the javascript console in your browser's developer tools to see if there's any javascript errors when you click on the link.

Other than that, your posted code looks in order.

Minor style suggestion though: you don't need to pass `:id => activity.id` to the path helper, just use: `club_club_accounting_delete_path(activity)`.

If you encounter any error messages, post them back in your answer.